# Ошибка "import of android.R : this response: R cannot be resolved"

Tags: activity, android, eclipse

Доброе время суток всем! Помогите новичку.
Это моё первое приложение для андроида. Действовал строго по инструкции, но столкнулся с проблемой.

Вот статья, которой я руководствовался - [itclubtomsk.ru/blogs/mvc-4/pishem-pervoe-prilozhenie-dlja-android.html](http://itclubtomsk.ru/blogs/mvc-4/pishem-pervoe-prilozhenie-dlja-android.html).

Вот код:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ошибки

1. `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`
2. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

> import of android.R : this response: R cannot be resolved - Android error

В обеих случаях подчеркивает R.

Я попробовал импортировать

```
import android.R;
```

но результатов не дало. Помогите пожалуйста, объясните в чем проблема.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импортировать `R.android` точно не нужно. У Вас в `res/` есть `xml` с меню? Имя сверили?

Comment: добавил xml файл, если вы про этот ))

Comment: всё решил, неверно подключил андроид SDK.
подсказка что android.Р не нужно импортирывать мне очень помогла, так как я думал что там проблема

Comment: не подскажите как правильно подкючить андроид sdk  а то и  у меня такая же проблема.